# Orientation is being incorrectly changed in an iPad Application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios32

I have an application that starts with a Login screen (UIViewController) and then once the user completes the login, the rest of the application is managed by a SplitViewController. The problem I'm having is that when the SplitViewController is first displayed, it overwrites the current screen orientation, it forces portrait mode even if I'm holding the device in landscape.

I've searched all the settings, my code and the xml in the .xib files, I can't find anything that would cause the orientation to change. Has anyone else had this issue, or can anyone think of another place to look for the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that if the SplitViewController isn't your first View to be loaded, the app won't initialize correctly. I solved the problem by changing my login view from being the view the app loads with to being a full screen dialog that covers the SplitViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `UISplitViewController` the "root" view controller of your app? Judging by your description, it's not clear, and it needs to be for an iPad app to work properly. (There are dozens of related questions to that gotcha here on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: That line of reasoning sounds about right. I wasn't aware that there was a root controller that had any special properties. The flow of my app is set up in my AppDelegate. I edited the boilerplate code that was generated when I told xcode to create a SplitViewController project. Instead of building the SplitViewController, I load a different nib for the login screen and then once login is complete I load the SplitViewController.

Comment: Ok, so I looked in to it. Yes the SplitViewController was the root all along, so this isn't the issue. Still haven't been able to figure it out...